# Parsing AWS JSON with JQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to parse JSON output from the AWS CLI.  What I'm looking for are security group names with specific tags below them.  The two commands that work are

```
$aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq  -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupName'
default
mysqlsg
apachesg
default
```

Then I run

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq  -r '.SecurityGroups[].Tags[]|select(.Key == "Service")'
{
  "Key": "Service",
  "Value": "default"
}
{
  "Key": "Service",
  "Value": "MySQL"
}
{
  "Key": "Service",
  "Value": "Apache"
}
{
  "Key": "Service",
  "Value": "default"
}
```

I'd like each group to have the Service Tag below it so I tried this but it didn't work.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq  -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupName,.SecurityGroups[].Tags[]|select(.Key == "Service")'
jq: error (at <stdin>:225): Cannot index string with string "Key"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I'd like each group to have the Service Tag">

Comment: Each security group has the tag with Key Service.  I'd like to display the Group Name with the Tags that have Key Service and it's value below it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `aws-cli` query parameters, try the below and it should work.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[].{Tags:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],GroupName:GroupName}'
```

output

```
    {
        "Tags": "demo",
        "GroupName": "demo"
    }
```